# Uninstalling a python module in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, uninstallation

I have to delete a python module named "django" (a popular one), because I installed the wrong version (1.3 - beta in py-2.6).

How to uninstall this module?
Please explain, because I've used python only in Windows and never in Ubuntu.

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: I installed it according to the instructions in the django site

Comment: You shouldn't install stuff in Ubuntu/Debian globally using anything other than `apt` unless it's in a controlled location like /usr/local/. If you do want a specific version of Django not in the repositories, you should use virtualenv and install it locally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

go to the python shell

```
 >> import django
```

```
 django.__path__
```

copy the path

on the shell

```
 sudo  rm -r path
```

Comment: No. There might be other dependencies.

Comment: True, but in this case, there aren't. Django is self-contained.

Comment: python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django; print(django.__path__)"

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo aptitude install python-pip
sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

Comment: No this is not recommended at all! It create a new django that contains the old version of django inside