# How to uninstall Keras?

Tags: python, theano, keras

I have installed Keras using this command:

```
sudo pip install keras
```

It installed properly and worked fine until I tried to import application modules:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
Using Theano backend.
Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named applications.vgg16
```

I came across [this link which recommends](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/3OpfQHzCk64) to uninstall Keras and directly install Keras from GitHub:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/fchollet/keras.git
```

Before reinstalling Keras from GitHub, I tried to unistall Keras using this command but it throws this error:

```
sudo pip uninstall keras
Can't uninstall 'Keras'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python setup.py uninstall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall)

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905264/keras-importerror-no-module-named-data-utils

Comment: it is not recommended to use sudo with pip , `pip install --user packagename` is better.

Comment: you should run using like python3 test.py

Answer (score 18):

You can simply try from the following command:

```
pip uninstall keras
```

Answer (score 9):

I followed [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5959706/996366) to solve my problem

```
>> import keras
>> keras.__path__
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras']

#copy the path
>> sudo  rm -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras

#re installation
>> sudo pip install git+https://github.com/fchollet/keras.git
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, It gave `keras is already installed` error when executing`pip install` command. So, I run `sudo pip uninstall keras` to remove keras from pip cache, then install it again succesfully.

Answer (score 7):

uninstall keras:

```
pip uninstall keras -y
```

reinstall with specific version

```
pip install -Iv keras==2.1.4
```

Answer (score 3):

In Anaconda prompt type

```
conda uninstall keras
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you really want to do is not to uninstall the keras, but use the `keras.applications.vgg16`.
The following checklist will help you to clarify the issue.

- **Keras version**: confirm the version of the keras is latest (now 2.0.5)
- **Backend**: Theano/Tensorflow or the other
- **Device**: GPU or CPU
- **Python version**: 2 or 3 and use Anaconda or not
- **Operating system**: Mac, Windows, Linux, and so on

I recommend to check **latest keras, TensorFlow backend(CPU mode), Python3** setting at first. It will solve various problems.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: Since this edit was rejected for Eka's answer,which worked  for me, I added this as answer for folks who have to use Windows.

```
import keras
print(keras.__path__)
C:\\Users\\oyo\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py36\\lib\\site-packages\\keras
```

Now in Command Prompt

```
cd C:\Users\oyo\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\

rmdir keras
```

Answer (score 1):

Please also check the Anaconda environment if you are using any

Answer (score 1):

you can  uninstall from conda by using this command.
`conda uninstall keras`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo pip uninstall git+https://github.com/fchollet/keras.git
```

If that does not work, what you can see after `sudo pip list`?

Comment: @Greenonline you can see the exact name of keras module installed, I think that the name should be include keras but not is only keras, removing it keras should be removed.

Comment: Eh? Why are you addressing the comment to me? I think there has been some mistake. I merely edited your answer for formatting reasons. If you wish to up[date your answer with more info please use the edit button and not the comments...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command.

```
 pip install --ignore-installed keras==<version>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ignore the uninstall process
Just install new version keras version is fine

`sudo pip install keras`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with

`sudo pip -U install keras`

Comment: That is for installing or upgrading keras. The question asked for uninstallation.

Comment: The ultimate goal is for reinstall Keras tho.