# Could not downgrade the version of keras due to an OSError:[Errno 2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to downgrade the version of keras and whenever i try to install or uninstall it, I run into this error.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras-2.7.0.dist-info/RECORD'
```

I first tried pip uninstall keras, it gave the above error

I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435526/11115848 but still it gives same error on installing again and moreover shows a prompt to install keras and that keras can no longer be imported in my files

This question is a repost of already posted question as advised to post it here. Original question:- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/104181/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-no-such-file-or-directory-usr-l

Comment: Hi! Could you try Keras installation in fresh environment?

Comment: The issue is resolved dw and the question can be closed